# understanding of addresses in dynamically loaded library

Tags: c, dll, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, memory-layout

I have a `foo2` function defined in `foo.so`, when I dynamic loaded into the main program, I try to understand the base address and function `foo`'s address. The code is the following:

```
void (* foo2)(void) = (void (*)(void))dlsym(loaded_so_handle, "foo2");
Dl_info info;
dladdr(&foo2, &info);
void * baseaddr = info.dli_fbase;
printf("base:%p, foo:%p, diff: %p\n", baseaddr, foo2,  (long)foo2 - (long)baseaddr);
```

I expect the `diff` printout should also be constant (given a fixed shared object `.so`). But the print out is sth like below; the address `diff` is not constant?

```
$ ./a.out
base: 0x238c660, foo:0x2af0350ad860, diff: 0x2af032d21200
$ ./a.out
base: 0x1de4660, foo:0x2ac564cd7860, diff: 0x2ac562ef3200
```

Updates:

After turning off ASLR, the diff is static, but also is the `base` address. Is it normal that .so object is always loaded to a fixed position/section in the main program's address space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addresses of functions and variables contained in dynamic loaded libraries are randomized to avoid security breaches.

Comment: I have to ask one more question though (as also updated in the OP):

After turning off ASLR, the diff is static, and so is the base address. Is it normal that .so object is always loaded to a fixed position/section in the main program's address space?